# How to Countdown time in seconds in C?

Tags: c

I made a game in C where you move in order to get some random points on screen, but I want to set a time of playing, like 30 seconds for a game, until it ends.How can I do it ?

I know is a function clock, but I want something more detailed, how to use it or something else just to work.

Comment: use an [`alarm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) ?

Comment: Something that counts x seconds.From x seconds to 0.

Comment: If you can please edit the question and make it more specific so it can be search and helpful to others. it would also change the question status to active from hold. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
    {
    clock_t begin;
    double time_spent;
    unsigned int i;

    /* Mark beginning time */
    begin = clock();
    for (i=0;1;i++)
        {
        //printf("hello\n");
        /* Get CPU time since loop started */
        time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if (time_spent>=30.0)
            break;
        }
    return(0);
    }
```

This is a possible solution for checking if 30 seconds are passed after the execution started. you can use the code for 30 seconds of delay, but you have to check it at every iteration and arrange your code accordingly.

Comment: That's a great solution, Jay Joshi. It is clear and portable.

Comment: Always welcome, friend :D

Comment: Instead of dividing by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` every time through the loop, why not multiply by it once at the beginning? Also, throw in some short calls to `usleep(3)` to avoid using too much CPU in the loop.

Comment: Its about letting him know way to do so.. how to do is on his code you know.. he has made game, ofcourse he can run this anytime he want. Even after one second.. that would be just 30 times Calling this code :)